# Xcode build settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I have a problem with the build settings for my project, there are no drop downs, see image.
I realise a similar question has been asked already, but that doesn't provide an answer for my issue.

image: [Build settings screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m31m5i7by0i1spt/xcodeBuildError.png)

(as a new user, i am unable to attach image here, please see the dropbox link above)

I started the development of the project on a different mac and then updated and completed it on my new mac. my profiles are all installed and are listed in the provisioning section xcode organiser.

I can build and test in the sim and on my device OK, however when i try to change the code sign settings for release, i am unable to see the drop down as indicated in the documentation.

Any help/suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it would solve the problem but can you try and create a new Configuration "Distribute" for example under Project settings -> Info -> configuration. And see if you get the same problem.

Comment: Hi Anila, I have tried that, and I am able to add a new config, but it just says 'No Configurations Set'

Comment: and if you open the configuration details by clicking on the arrow, does it have the target set?

Comment: Clicking on the arrow shows the name of my project, none for the set see image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mtdj5t4m78aa8oe/xcodeBuildError2.png

Comment: it's ok, and now if you try and set the profile in build settings?

Comment: @Anila This is the bit i can't do, there is no selection available for this, when i click in the box for the code signing box for release, it just turns into a text input field and not a dropdown list where i can select the profile...

Comment: that's exactly why i suggested you create a new configuration. Try duplicating the "Debug" configuration under configurations list, and name it "Distribute" and see what happens.

Comment: Anila, Thank you for the advice, I created the distribute config, and its still the same.

Now fixed, thanks to NSIllusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Editor - > Show values. It will work like charms:)

[image]